# Submitting JCL through filezilla or winScp

Tags: ftp, mainframe, winscp, filezilla, jcl

I used submit JCL with FTP(example below). Is there any way to do something like this with FileZilla or winScp?

FTP example:

```
ftp  
open servername   
user   
password  
quote site filetype=jes   
mdel *.*   
put c:\jcl.txt  
ls   
disconnect   
quit
```

Comment: You have already asked this on WinSCP support forum: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23144#88424 - And you didn't respond to my question.